# Help setting up a secondary authoritative DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, redhat, djbdns, authoritative, tinydns

We have three Authoritative DNS servers and three recursive/caching DNS servers on my campus.

Authoritative servers

DNS1- Windows 2003
DNS2- Old Red Hat -----> Replacing w/ newer version
DNS3- Windows 2008  (I installed)

Caching and Recursive resolvers servers

Server1- Windows 2003
Server2- CentOS 5.2 (I installed)
Server3- CentOS 5.3 (I installed)

I am replacing DNS2 with a newer Red Hat version, but have no documentation on how it was implemented.  I have setup caching and windows authoritative servers, but not a linux secondary authoritative server.  I have a perl script from the original server that pulls data from our DNS1 server.  We use DJBDNS and TinyDNS on our linux servers.  Our Network Engineer says the DNS2 server I am replacing is an authoritative server that **doesn't** need to be caching, but the only instructions I see is for an Authoritative server that **does** caching as well. Can someone point me in the right directions.  I thought I was on the right track with using [these instructions](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/29/how-to-setup-tinydns-server-for-soho/) but when I query my new dns server I get "No response from server", I have temporarily disabled iptables to eliminate it from being an issue.

ps -aux | grep dns

avahi     3493  0.0  0.2   2600  1272 ?        Ss   Apr24   0:05 avahi-daemon: running [newdns2.local]

root      5254  0.0  0.1   3920   680 pts/0    R+   09:56   0:00 grep dns

root      6451  0.0  0.0   1528   308 ?        S    Apr29   0:00 supervise tinydns

dnslog    6454  0.0  0.0   1540   308 ?        S    Apr29   0:00 multilog t ./main

tinydns   9269  0.0  0.0   1652   308 ?        S    Apr29   0:00 /usr/local/bin/tinydns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it.

This guide explains it step by step. (without caching)

http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/29/how-to-setup-tinydns-server-for-soho/

Answer (score 0):

Deciding whether the nameserver will be caching or not is fundamental. BIND trained people to consider them "kinda same thing", but they are two radically different tasks and they are served by two completely separate (and independent) tools in the djbdns distribution.

If you want to replicate an authoritative server, the way recommended by tinydns is to just transfer the "data.cdb" file (the zone database binary file) from the primary server to the secondary or secondaries. Of course this will force the secondaries to ONLY serve the same zones of the primary. If you want to use the secondary servers to serve other zones as well, you need to transfer them via AXFR (axfrget) and rebuild the database file at the secondaries. Or use a secondary DNS service online to do all for you.